# Is it recommended to always versioning Core Data's data model?

Tags: ios, core-data, versioning, data-modeling, core-data-migration

Predictably, my app won't have changes in its data model in future updates, but just in case... will it be a problem to deliver the first version of the app without having set its Model Version, and then starting setting it in subsequent app versions only if migrations needed? Or should I deliver the first version of the app having already set a Model Version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, maybe you don't need enable versioning in the first version.

BUT, for example, if you enable it in the second version, and forgot change `CoreData` initializing code?

I prefer add automatic version migrating since first version of app, even if I don't plan to change model